# how to check different date formats in java

Tags: java

I am getting different date formats below `dd-MM-yyyy,dd/MM/yyyy`,`yyyy-MM-dd`,`yyyy/MM/dd`

```
SimpleDateFormat sm1 = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");
String date = "01-12-2013";
System.out.println("Date 1 is "+sm1.parse(date));
date = "2013-12-01";
System.out.println("Date 1 is "+sm1.parse(date));
```

the same simple date format gives the below result eventhough date format is wrong(ie:-2013-12-01).Below the results.

```
 Date 1 is Sun Dec 01 00:00:00 IST 2013
 Date 1 is Sun Jun 05 00:00:00 IST 7
```

Answer (score 5):

You need to [`setLenient(false)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/DateFormat.html#setLenient%28boolean%29) to make `parse()` method `throw` [`ParseException`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/ParseException.html) for unparsable case

Answer (score 1):

I have tried Jigar Joshi's answer.
==========================code=======================================

```
SimpleDateFormat sm1 = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");
sm1.setLenient(false);
String date = "01-12-2013";
System.out.println("Date 1 is "+sm1.parse(date));
date = "2013-12-01";
System.out.println("Date 1 is "+sm1.parse(date));
```

=========================Result========================================

```
Date 1 is Sun Dec 01 00:00:00 CST 2013
Exception in thread "main" java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "2013-12-01"
    at java.text.DateFormat.parse(DateFormat.java:337)
    at workflow.Test.main(Test.java:14)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your date format is `dd-MM-yyyy`.  That means the parser is expecting some day, month, and year format.

From [the `SimpleDateFormat` documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html#number):  **the number of pattern letters in a `Number` type formatter is the minimum**.  So, while `2013` wouldn't make sense in our mind, it fits within the formatter's bounds.

You have provided `2013-12-01` as to fit into that format.  What it appears the formatter is doing is providing December 1 (insert timezone here), and then adding 2,013 days to it.

That turns out to be [June 6, 7 AD](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=December+1%2C+1+%2B+2%2C013+days).  There's some wiggle room for your timezone (I'm not sure which of the five timezones IST represents [is actually yours](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IST)).

So, believe it or not...the formatter is correct.  Be *very* careful as to what kind of format you specify or allow in your dates!

If you don't want that parsed, then specify `setLenient(false)` on your instance of `sm1`.